# Compile webots for Python 3.6 for Windows

Tags: simulation, webots

I would appreciate if someone could assist me in compiling webots source for Python 3.6 to allow me and others to use TensorFlow with it. I already tried but apparently there is something not mentioned about a missing step. Thanks

Link:
https://github.com/omichel/webots/issues/105

Comment: what was the result of your attempt?

Comment: go to http://sysinternals.com (redirects to microsoft since MS purchased sysinternals) ....... download `Process Monitor` ..... run it  ......... compile the "webots for python" ........ when the "unable to find" errors show, stop the compiler ...... go to process monitor and search for `webots/Device.hpp` or just `Device.hpp`  ....... that will tell you where the compiler tried to find the file ............ lots of useful utilities at sysinternals